# Creating a JSON dynamically using Dictionary key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to generate a JSON file in the below format.

```
var highlighted_color = {
  mo: '#2980b9',
  fl: '#27ae60',
  or: '#8e44ad'
}
```

The Javascript code I have so far gone through each key-value pair grabs the data, I am however unable to understand how to process from here on.

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, values]) => {
  var item = {}
  item[key] = values;
});
```

The key has the object and values has the color code

Comment: please post `data` object also

Comment: are you doing this in node? I am not sure how to do it from the frontend. but if you want to create a new file on the server's side, you are gonna need `fs.write` : https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_string_position_encoding_callback

Comment: Your desired output format as shown in your question is JavaScript and not JSON. JSON is a string representation of an object or an array and it can be generated most easily by applying `JSON.stringify()` on the source object/array.

Comment: Your question is how to create a JSON __file__ from the object? Where the file should be saved? How is json.net related to the question?

Comment: @AlanceJacob - I removed the [tag:json.net] tag as it is for a library used in c# and other .Net applications, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will get you the required string (the keys are surrounded by double quotes, but otherwise it is exactly what you wanted):

```js
const data={
  mo: '#2980b9',
  fl: '#27ae60',
  or: '#8e44ad'
}
let res="var highlighted_color = "+JSON.stringify(data,null,2);
console.log(res);
```

To put this string into a file (on a server) you could send it to
a PHP (or other) script on that server:

```
fetch('ScriptWillPutStringIntoFile.php?filename=colorData&str=var highlighted_color ='+res);

// the above works for SHORT bits of data (< 2014 bytes).
// For the general case you should use something like this:

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'ScriptWillPutStringIntoFile.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    filename
    str: res
}));
```